# Changing the path of the "addItem" layout action

Tags: magento-enterprise, layout, css

I am using the following code in the Layout Update XML section of a CMS page:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/specific_page_style.css</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

The path being referred to on the page is: http://www.sample.org/skin/frontend/base/default/css/specific_page_style.css

Since the rest of my skin files are in /skin/frontend/enterprise/sampleorg/*, I would like addItem to be able to point to the CSS directory that resides there. Is it possible to do this with the skin_css type, or do I have to use a different type and place the full path in the name?

Additionally, am I approaching this in the right way, and how would I have figured this out for myself? I could not find the addItem definition in any official docs.

Edit: In System > Configuration > Design, the following fields are set:

```
Current Package Name: enterprise
Templates: sampleorg
Skin (Images / CSS): sampleorg
```

There are no package or theme exceptions set.

Comment: Did you set your `template` and `package` to *enterprise* and *sampleorg* under `system > configuration > general > design` ?

Comment: @Sander-MageStackDay2015 Edited to include this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Magento should pick up your `specific_page_style.css` in the `enterprise/sampleorg` directory if it's in there. When it falls back to `base/default` that means it can't find the file in there.

Check if the file owner and rights are set correctly. If you want to make an exception so that the file always goes to `base/default` add an exception under `System > Configuration > General > Design > Template > Skin`

Comment: Thank you, Sander. a triple-check of paths and filenames returned an issue that I created. Knowing that base/default is the fallback helped (even though base/default also returns a 404...)

Comment: can you call the file via a direct link? And if so, what does it return?

Comment: Sorry, it is fixed now. The file is returned via direct link too. What I meant with the last comment is that even if the file exists in no places, it will use the base/default link, which was making me think it always used that path.